# Singularities of matrix element of composite local operator in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, singularities, correlation-functions, matrix-elements

Consider a state $|\psi\rangle$ in a quantum field theory and a local operator $\mathcal{O}(x)$.  It's known that the $n$-point function

$\langle \psi | \mathcal{O}(x_1) \cdots \mathcal{O}(x_n) | \psi\rangle$

is singular for certain $x_i$ (for example, when two of the $x_i$ are coincident or null separated).  My question is: given two states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ (which for simplicity we can take to be orthogonal), can anything be said about the divergences of the matrix element

$\langle \psi | \mathcal{O}(x_1) \cdots \mathcal{O}(x_n) | \phi\rangle$?

For instance, does the above object have any singularities?  If it does, are they related in any known way to singularities of the corresponding correlator in the states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$?  (Also note that I'm only interested in Hadamard states.)

Answer (score 2):

The statement that the coinciding point singularities do not depend on the choice of states is the statement that Wilson's [operator product expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion) holds.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but these off-diagonal matrix elements (the so-called "strange correlator") has been studied in detail in https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.247202.