# Universality of leading singularities in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, singularities, correlation-functions

I have now seen at several places claims of the form "each state looks like the vacuum at short distances" or similiarly that the "leading singularity of correlation functions is universal", i.e.

$$<A|\phi(x)\phi(y)|A> \sim <\Omega|\phi(x)\phi(y)|\Omega>,$$

for $x,y$ close, where $A$ is some state and $\Omega$ the vacuum. This is always stated as a general fact without any further explanation of reference (e.g. below Eq. 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.02837).

Why is that so?

EDIT: I have now found [Singularities of matrix element of composite local operator in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310368/)

which indicates that this is due to the existence of the OPE, which in my mind would replace the two-point function with a one-point function. This one-point function would still be state dependent or am I missing something?